# c++ Tightly Coupled Template Definitions, Infinitely Recurring Template Parameters

Tags: c++

Consider the following simple and usual case:

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct A {
    B &b;
    A(B &b_): b{b_} {
    }
};

struct B {
    A a;
    B(): a{*this} {
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

This coding pattern is used for tightly coupling a class to another via composition. Now, let's assume that I want to do this via templates. Consider the following:

```
template <typename Bparam>
struct A;

template <typename Aparam>
struct B;

template <typename Bparam>
struct A {
    Bparam &b;
    A(Bparam &b_): b{b_} {
    }
};

template <typename Aparam>
struct B {
    Aparam a;
    B(): a{*this} {
    }
};

int main() {
    B<A<B>> b; // infinitely many template parameters here ???
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to implement such a thing in C++?

Comment: having the same name for template parameters and struct is confusing

Comment: I suggest reading about [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It doesn't solve the problem directly but still may help.

Comment: @Tyker I fixed that

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Thank you for your comment, I know about CRTP. I can change my design to use that and avoid this issue. However, I am curious if there is a fix in C++ regarding this.

Comment: A or B aren't type they are template type so you would need a terminating type to terminate the recursive type and compiler have limits on the amont of recursive type the can so it won't be infinite but very high

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
template<template<typename> class Bp>
struct A;

template<typename Ap>
struct B;

template<template<typename> class Bp>
struct A {
    Bp<A>& b;
    A(Bp<A>& b_) : b(b_) {}
};

template<typename Ap>
struct B {
    Ap a;
    B() : a{*this} {}
};

int main() {
    B<A<B>> b;
}
```